# how to replace in a string

Tags: python, str-replace

i have a url, which have to alter base on output from other function.

```
rogues_detail_url = https://foo.bar.com/api/list_view.json?list=rogue_ap&fv_id=0&page_length=500&sort_col=acknowledged&sort_descend=false&start_row=0
rogues_detail_url.replace("500",foo())
```

`foo()` returns an integer value.

just in case if i was doing it wrong i also tried 
    `rogues_detail_url.replace("500","1000")`

Neither of them seem to work. Printing the url after i execute the statement, prints the same url

Comment: `rogues_detail_url = rogues_detail_url.replace("500", str(foo()))`?

Comment: Did you mean to put quotes around the string on the first statement?

Comment: `replace` doesn't *modify* the string, it *returns* the modified string :)

Comment: yes, i assigned it to some other variable, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, strings are never modified in-place. In fact, strings can't be modified at all. As such, methods such as `string.replace` return a modified copy.

In python, string methods generally do the following:

1. copy the original
2. modify the copy in some way
3. leave the original alone.
4. return the modified copy

You want to write:
`new_string = old_string.replace("500","1000")`

If you write only write `old_string.replace("500","1000")` then you just ignored/discarded the new modified string. `old_string` cannot be modified by `replace` or any other string method.